# Why Log out after verify phone number in asp.net identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net Identity in my project. In `VerifyPhoneNumber` view, when user confirm his phone number, he is logged out (`.AspNetApplicationCookie` is removed. I checked this from Resource tab inspect chrome).
Code of `VerifyPhoneNumber` action in `ManageController`:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}
string phoneNumber = UserManager.GetPhoneNumber(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var result = await UserManager.ChangePhoneNumberAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), phoneNumber, model.Code);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if (user != null)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
    }
    ViewBag.Message = "Complete";
    return View();

}
// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
ModelState.AddModelError("", "something wrong!");
return View(model);
```

Why this happens?

**Update**
I have set `validateInterval` for `SecurityStampValidator` to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ChangePhoneNumberAsync` [has this line](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs):

```
await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user).WithCurrentCulture();
```

Which causes the cookie expiration or re-validation.
If you don't want it, you have to inherit from the `UserManager<TUser>` class (create your CustomUserManager class) and then override the `ChangePhoneNumberAsync` method. Just use [the same code](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs) without the `UpdateSecurityStampInternal` line.

Answer (score 0):

Changing any security related information on the user (i.e password/phone number/email) automatically causes the cookie to expire by default (via the security stamp for the user getting flipped)

Comment: But I only confirm phone number, not change that!

Comment: How can I prevent change security stamp after phone confirmation?