# Update Identity User Claims in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currently trying to update the user's email/username from a mobile app to a Web API project. I'm currently using oauth and token authentication. When updating the identity user, the user becomes unauthenticated because the username and access token are no longer valid. From what I have read, I must update the identity claims. This is what I have tried so far:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);

if (result)
{
    var identityUser =  await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

    identityUser.Email = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(value.Email, true);
    identityUser.UserName = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(value.Email, true);

    var identityResult = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(identityUser);

    if(identityResult.Succeeded)
    {
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

        await UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(identityUser.Id, identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name));
        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(identityUser.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, value.Email));

        identity.RemoveClaim(identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, value.Email));

        authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant =
                    new AuthenticationResponseGrant(
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                    new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false });
     }
  return Ok();
}
```

However, it still shows the previous email when using `User.Identity.Name` and the claims for the user within the `authenticationManager` have not been updated either. I'm not sure what else to do as there isn't much documentation on this for Web API. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you checking same request or a subsequent one ?

Comment: Have a look at [this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/119868) and [this answer](https://forums.asp.net/t/1969982.aspx?Update+User+Claim+not+Taking+Efect+Why+).

Comment: I want to check each subsequent requests.

Comment: I see that you're `return Ok()` Which seems to imply that you are doing this from an HTTP Response instead of doing this from your Authentication Middleware

Comment: @johnny5, yes, I'm doing it in the controller, similar to how the default does the creation from the AccountController when creating/registering the user.

Comment: Won’t your claims be overridden the next time you authenticate a request?

Comment: @johnny5 Not sure what's happening. I can see claims that I'm unable to update but I'm able to see the new claims but the logged in user is the old username/email instead of the updated. Therefore the returning requests fail cause the updated user is not authenticated anymore.

Comment: Why are you changing the username/email, instead of just adding a new claim AlternateEmail/AlternateUsername or something etc

Comment: Users need the ability to update their email and as of right now, their username and email are one in the same.

Comment: a small repro example on git would help

Comment: Is the web app sending the same token or an updated token after this process?

Comment: It’s sending the same token.

Comment: It's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588153/why-log-out-after-verify-phone-number-in-asp-net-identity/44485315#44485315

Comment: I see you aren't validating your existing claim. Are you sure you're actually removing the right claim? // check for existing claim and remove it
                var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst(key);
                if (existingClaim != null)
                    identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);

Comment: Can´t you just use the `SigninManager.SigninAsync( YOUR_NEW_IDENTITY_USER)` ?

Comment: maybe use this method `UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user)` and also, you should probably return a new token so your client can use it in the subsequent requests?

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is that claim which represents user's name is not updated in `ClaimsIdentity` you are using in the last step.

The easiest way to perform the update is to use [`SignInManager<TUser, TKey>.SignIn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dn896559(v=vs.108)) method

```
signInManager.SignIn(identityUser, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
```

This is also an ASP.NET Identity idiomatic way since it is using associated `IClaimsIdentityFactory` to create claims for new identities.

---

Complete example

```
static async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateEmailAsync<TUser>(
    IPrincipal principal,
    UserManager<TUser, string> userManager,
    SignInManager<TUser, string> signInManager,
    string newEmail
)
    where TUser : class, IUser<string>
{
    string userId = principal.Identity.GetUserId();
    IdentityResult result = await userManager.SetEmailAsync(userId, newEmail);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        // automatically confirm user's email
        string confirmationToken = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId);
        result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, confirmationToken);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            TUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user != null)
            {
                // update username
                user.UserName = newEmail;
                await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                // creates new identity with updated user's name
                await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            }

            // succeded
            return result;
        }
    }

    // failed
    return result;
}
```

Then you can just call it from your code

```
string newEmail = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(value.Email, true);
IdentityResult result = await UpdateEmailAsync(identityUser, UserManager, SignInManager, newEmail);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return Ok();
}
```